# How to make just a card in a bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I try to make this

[image]

But i don't know to do that

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-3 me-3" style="background-color: #F1F3F8; border-radius: 10px;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <img src="/src/photos/event_upcoming.svg" class="img-fluid mx-auto" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <p>Срок обучения<br>6 месяцев</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide more detail as to what you have tried. Have you looked at the Bootstrap documentation for cards? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the output, let me know if any doubts with the CSS

```css
  .c-light {
    color: #7e8591;
  }
  .c-black {
    color: black;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div
    class="col-8 me-8"
    style="background-color: #f1f3f8; border-radius: 10px"
  >
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 p-4">
        <img src="https://placehold.co/150x150" class="img-fluid mx-auto" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-8 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-start">
        <p class="c-light">
          Срок обучения<br /><span class="c-black">6 месяцев</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>

<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve that like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main-card">
  <div class="icon-holder">
    YOUR ICON
  </div>

  <div class="title-holder">
    <p>Title</p>
    <p>Sub-Title</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main-card {
    ** THIS WILL HAVE THE CARD DESIGN CSS ** 
    **AND**
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.title-holder {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```